# Laravel Elixir includePaths not working

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-sass, laravel-elixir

I'm trying Laravel Elixir and want to include bootstrap with includePaths but it does not work. Where am I going wrong?

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/'
}

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("style.scss", 'public/assets/css/', {includePaths: [paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/']})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a reason that you want to do includePaths in your gulpfile, but for bootstrap you don't have to. The bootstrap include path is already configured out of the box in /node_modules/laravel-elixir/ingredients:

```
elixir.extend('sass', function(src, output, options) {

    options = _.extend({
        outputStyle: inProduction ? 'compressed' : 'nested',
        includePaths: [elixir.config.bowerDir + "/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets"]
    }, options);

    return compile({
        compiler: 'Sass',
        pluginName: 'sass',
        pluginOptions: options,
        src: src,
        output: output,
        search: '**/*.+(sass|scss)'
    });
});
```

So all you should have to do is, in your gulpfile:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("style.scss");
});
```

And then in your style.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I think you have to set your .bowerrc file to:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/bower_components"
}
```

but it looks like you have already done that.

Comment: Your answer is really to a different question, the package in ./vender/bower_components could be anything else and this question remains unanswered. I've been having trouble including alternate includePaths and having them be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an accepted answer but I got something like this to work.

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': '/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/',
}

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css', {
        includePaths: [
            __dirname + paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/'
        ]
    });

    mix.version("css/app.css");
});
```

Where `bower_components` is installed in the laravel root dir.

(From: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/gulpfile-elixir-merge-scss-includepaths)

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is using this line to compile sass or less files sitting in your vendor folder:

```
mix.less("../../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");
```

Note: I used "composer require twbs/boostrap" to get the complete package. No bower needed.

Edit:

I output the compiled css file to the resource folder to combine it with other css files:

```
mix.less("../../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less", 'resources/css');


mix.styles([
    "bootstrap.css"
], 'public/css/app.css');
```